# Как отправить POST через axios в telegra.ph API?

Tags: javascript, json, api, axios

Отправляю пост в telegraph API c помощью axios.post() в nodejs.
в ответ получаю, что невалидный токен.
хотя, если отправлять с помощь axios.get() то все получается. мне нужен post потому что в гет не принимает длинных текстов так как данные передаются в параметрах url

возможно, передаю не правильный объект или что-то не там где нужно застрингифаил.

вот код:

```js
const requestTelegraphPOST = async (url, data) => {
    try {
        return await axios.post(url, data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}

    requestTelegraphPOST('https://api.telegra.ph/createPage', {
        access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
        title,
        content
    }).then(data => {
        if (data.data.result) {
            const telegraphPostUrl = data.data.result.url
            sendPost(telegraphPostUrl)
        } else {
            console.log(chalk.yellow('Не удалось создать пост. Ответ от Telegraph API:'))
            console.log(data.data)
        }
    }).catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Здесь документация по API https://telegra.ph/api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего уходит пустое тело запроса.

Для отправки данных через `post` в `axios` нужно ещё пара моментов. Можно попробовать добавить заголовки, в вашем случае это будет:

```
const requestTelegraphPOST = async (url, data) => {
    try {
        return await axios.post(url, data, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

Или есть вариант ещё собирать `data` через `FormData` и её уже отдавать в `post`:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('access_token', ACCESS_TOKEN);
...
```

Мне больше нравится второй вариант.

Comment: я думаю, это немного не то, что нужно. при отправке get запроса я кодирую url encodeURI(requestUrl)

а здесь же (в post) в content нужно отправлять застрингиaаеный объект c нодам, насколько я понимаю. или же наоборот нужно отправлять обычный обхект, а стрингифаить всю дату. или же просто хэдер json

Comment: в общем победил с помощью библиотеки request,с axios так и не разобрался

```js
    request.post(
      'https://api.telegra.ph/createPage',
      {
        json: {
            access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
            title,
            content,
        },
      },
      (error, res, body) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error)
          return
        }
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
        console.log(body)
      }
    )
```